# Json Decode Error While loading multiple files from directory

Tags: python, json

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import collections
import os


path = '/home/vinay/hdfs/kafka-logs/event_tablenames.txt'

file_read = '/home/vinay/hdfs/kafka-logs/hdfs_events/'
table_file = '/home/hdfs/vinay/kafka-logs/events_tables/'
con_json = '/home/vinay/hdfs/kafka-logs/json_to_txt/'

os.chdir(file_read)
files=os.listdir('.')

for file in files:
    line = file.split('.')[0]
    with open(file ,'r') as f:
        print (json.load(f))
        data = json.load(f)
        key = data[line]
        od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(key.items()))
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(od.items()), columns=['col_name', 'type'])
        df['col_name'].to_csv(con_json + line + '.txt',sep='\t', index=False, header=False)
```

Below is a full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "events_match_hdfs.py", line 29, in <module>
      data = json.load(f)
    File "/home/vinay/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 268, in load
      parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    File "/home/vinay/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
      return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    File "/home/vinay/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
      obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    File "/home/vinay/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
      raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: For future questions / answers please refer to this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for help with formatting your question

Comment: You are calling `json.load(f)` twice on the same file pointer. The second time you have already reached the end of the file and there's nothing more to read. An empty string is invalid json. What is the expected output here? Just remove the first `print(json.load(f))`. You can `print(data)` instead after you have parsed the json file.

Comment: @Håken Lid: You just said what was already in my answer was posted several hours before your comment.

Comment: Yes. It's clear that your answer is correct. I added my comment since the asker claims that there's still a problem. There might be some information missing from the question, or they might not have entirely understood your answer. @vinaykn should either accept your answer or add a [mcve] to the question if there's something else that's also wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Json filename was not proper,and the size was zero.Due to that it was
  throwing error.
  Thanks all for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show the full traceback from the error in your question, so this is a just a guess.

I think the problem is because you're trying to do `json.load(f)` twice on the same file. The first one consumes the entire file, so the second one fail. Try changing the first couple of lines after opening the file to this:

```
with open(file ,'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print(data)
```

Comment: Tried with this also,it did nt help

Comment: complete Traceback has been added.Thanks in Adavance.

Comment: vinay kn: Hmm, it still looks to me like my guess was correct. The traceback seems to be show that the second call on the line `data = json.load(f)` is basically not finding any data. Regardless, making two calls in row like that to `json.load(f)` won't ever work.